# Vuetify props aren't being registered (Vue 3.2.13, Vuetify nightly 3.0.0)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

```
<v-btn
  icon
  color="white"
>
  <v-icon>mdi-account</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

[vuetify button not using icon prop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgB08.png)

package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --port $(grep PORT .env | cut -d '=' -f2)",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.5.10",
    "@mdi/font": "5.9.55",
    "@vue/apollo-option": "^4.0.0-alpha.16",
    "autoprefixer": "^10",
    "canvas": "^2.9.0",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "pm2": "^5.2.0",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "roboto-fontface": "*",
    "tailwindcss": "^3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3",
    "vuetify": "npm:@vuetify/nightly@next",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0",
    "webfontloader": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.38.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-apollo": "~0.22.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-tailwind": "~3.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.4.7",
    "vue-loader": "^17.0.0",
    "vuetify-loader": "^2.0.0-alpha.0"
  }
}
```

App.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
import { loadFonts } from './plugins/webfontloader'

loadFonts()

createApp(App)
  .use(router)
  .use(store)
  .use(vuetify)
  .mount('#app')
```

./plugins/vuetify.js

```
// Styles
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import 'vuetify/styles'

// Vuetify
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'

export default createVuetify(
  // https://vuetifyjs.com/en/introduction/why-vuetify/#feature-guides
)
```

What have I done wrong? I haven't found any vuetify props that work, they all just seem to be ignored. Maybe it's just the version I'm using, but I haven't found anything that suggests that.

apparently this is too much code now so here's another line  stackoverflow :)

Comment: Can you share your vuetify file (`./plugins/vuetify`) too?

Comment: Just tried adding
`import * as components from 'vuetify/components'`
`import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'`
for fun, from https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/
didn't fix the issue

Comment: I just realized that I'm following the vuetify 2.x documentation and I'm stupid.
As far as I can tell there's no issues. The icon prop on buttons has changed, it no longer removes the background, and just makes the button round.

Comment: Ha ha, easy mistake! You can add this as an answer to your own question and accept it, it may help someone else in a similar situation.

Answer (score 2):

I was using the 2.x documentation instead of 3.0.0 Beta. The icon prop on buttons has changed, it no longer removes the background, and just makes the button round. (I'm assuming the other problems I was having are becuase of the same thing)